# UTM variables in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utm

I can get referer by `request.referer`, my question is how can i get `utm variables` of the referer?

I have tried `params[:utm_source]` but it didn't work, `request.referer` gives me

`http://localhost:3001/show/?UTM_Source=newsletter&UTM_Medium=email&UTM_Campaign=unsubscribed`

Comment: UTM variables are just regular params aren't they?  Can you read them from your params?  Are they in the paramstring part of request.referer?

Comment: params[:utm_source] etc didn't work for me, while request.referer gives complete url, e.g http://localhost:3001/show/?UTM_Source=newsletter&UTM_Medium=email&UTM_Campaign=unsubscribed

Comment: Did you try `params[:UTM_Source]`

Comment: What is the value of `params`?  You should just be able to see if the params are there and what they're called.

Answer (score 1):

I mean really you should look at why you are unable to fetch this value using `params[:utm_source]` because it sounds like your code is not functioning correctly. This means my answer is a workaround and I wouldn't advise it:

**You can use `URI` and `CGI` to play with the URL**:

```
uri = URI.parse(request.referer)
parameters = CGI.parse(uri.query)

utm_source = parameters['UTM_Source'].first
```

In reality I think your problem is that you're using `params[:utm_source]` instead of `params[:UTM_Source]`. You have to remember that your `params` hash is **case-sensitive**